# Check if user is authenticated in laravel API route

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

So I know API routes are *not* supposed to rely on sessions authentication, but my idea was to create some API routes, that could be used if needs be by third-party with proper authentication, but that could also be used internally, ie called to get the data I need for my web pages.

I changed the LoginController so that every time a user logs in, a Personal Access token is generated and stored in the database. When logging out, this token is deleted.

So as not to expose the token to the client side, I would like to use a middleware, that would detect, on an API call, if the request comes from a user who is already authenticated. If that's the case, I would retrieve the Personal Access token that belongs to the user, attach it to the request, and pass it onto the API.

**Browser** -- *Query site.com/api/myRoute* --> **Middleware** adds user's token to request if Auth::check() -- *Pass-on request* --> **Controller**

I've created a dummy API route to see if I can detect whether a user is authenticated, but that doesn't seem to work... I guess because the 'auth' middleware is not included.. however, if I do include it, I get redirected to home on every request...

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        dd('Hello logged-in');
    } else {
        dd('Hello not logged-in');
    }
});
```

Any lead on how to achieve that much appreciated!

Comment: You need to follow this link to authenticate api user

[ https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport ]